# NeoBundle: Using a plugin from bundle directory without the installation?

Tags: vim, plugins

I suppose that it's a simple question, but I'm confused - how can I (in development purposes) load plugin, which was just copied into the **bundle** directory without the installation?

I have **bundle/my-plugin** directory, and this line in .vimrc

```
NeoBundle 'my-plugin'
```

But it seems that my plugins wasn't loaded automatically, although this was correct for Vundle.

**UPD**

My plugin contained an error, that prevented the loading.

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure if i do it the right, or best way but i do it like this (with vundle, should also work with any other)

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
" ...
call vundle#end()

" own plugins
set rtp+=~/.vim/own/vim-websearch
" ...
```

so i set the rtp myself for my own plugins myself and let vundle/neobundle/whatever only manage plugins which are not my own.
i have this directory structure:

```
~/.vim/
   |
   +--bundle/
   |    |
   |    +--plugin1/
   |    |
   |    +--plugin2/
   |    ...
   |
   +--own/
   |    |
   |    +--myplugin1/
   |    |
   |    +--myplugin2/
   |    ...
   ...
```

**edit:**
i kepp my plugins in a seperate directory because `:PluginClean` would delete them

Comment: Thx for the idea, it can be useful. But I found the source of problems - it was a mistake in my plugin.